# Can't access methods from another class - VB

Tags: vb.net, class, methods

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4qosA.jpg]

Example ^. I must be forgetting something or being really dumb.

Comment: Please use _text_ here. Copy-and-paste doesn't take that long to do, and the handy `{}` code-formatting button in the editor is actually _useful_. Try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing from the class, not the object, that's why only class methods get shown. Create inbox object first and use that to call the instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You're referencing the class, not the object.

```
inbox = new Inbox()
inbox.getEmail()
```

Answer (score 0):

create an object of Inbox class and then access it. If you want to access with Class name then you need to make the access member static.